# Is it possible to find the latest GitHub release of a repo with R?

Tags: r, github

I am looking for a way in R to get the latest release from a GitHub repository. For example, with the repository `acornamr/acorn-dashboard`, it would return the string `"v2.0.5"` (https://github.com/acornamr/acorn-dashboard/releases as of 2021-09-16).

I have tried to look at the source code of `remotes::install_github()` https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/blob/master/R/install-github.R but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up web scraping the page and extracting the right html element:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

read_html("https://github.com/acornamr/acorn-dashboard/releases/latest") |> 
  html_element(".release-header .f1") |>
  html_text() |>
  str_trim()
```

returns `"v2.0.5"`

The Pro of this method compare to @Stéphane Laurent solution with `library(gh)` is that you don't have to deal with `GitHub PAT`. The Cons is that it's dependant on HTML elements of GitHub.com that could evolve with the website design.

Answer (score 4):

With the **gh** package:

```
library(gh)

releases <- gh("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases", 
   owner = "acornamr",
   repo = "acorn-dashboard")

releases[[1]][["tag_name"]]
# "v2.0.5"
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to understand why the above command or even the example `gh("/users/hadley/repos")` fail on my machine with the following:

`Error: GitHub PAT must have one of these forms:
  * 40 hexadecimal digits (older PATs)
  * A 'ghp_' prefix followed by 36 to 251 more characters (newer PATs)
`

Running R 4.1 on Mac Intel with gh 1.3.0.

Comment: @tic-toc-choc Sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, slightly off topic to the OP, but related answer:

Microsoft stashes [daily snapshots](http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot) of CRAN. This free service is called MRAN.

You can set an MRAN daily snapshot as a `repos` option and `install.packages()` will use that repo when downloading. In this way, you can always download packages from a particular point in time. In your case, you always want the latest, so use `Sys.Date()` as your day to select.

```r
# MRAN snapshots
base_url <- "http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/"

# download from MRAN on this date
when <- Sys.Date() # or any date as YYYY-MM-DD

# set options
options(repos = list(CRAN = paste0(base_url, when)))

# the repo option set above defines where to download packages from
install.packages("my_package")
```

This is particularly useful when using Docker to build production-grade R code because you can ensure the packages installed into your image always come from the same, static date. I use something like this:

```
ARG WHEN

RUN R -e "options(repos = \
  list(CRAN = 'http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/${WHEN}')); \
  install.packages('my_package')"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, I am not sure that is possible with `remotes::install_github`. You are able to select which release you would like to download by using the following

```
remotes::install_github('acornamr/acorn-dashboard@v2.0.5')
```

For further reading, look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/remotes/readme/README.html)